# Jhipster build with Websocket and Vue, not authenticating or log in

Tags: java, vue.js, vuetify.js, jhipster, spring-websocket

I try to build using Jhipster using this setup, run server (gradlew -x webapp) and frontend (npm start) successfully, but couldn't log in with the default admin/user.

setup:

- application type > Monolithic application
- base name application > jhipster
- spring webflux > N
- package name > com.mycompany.myapp
- authentication type > HTTP Session Auth (stateful)
- database type > SQL
- production db > MySQL
- development db > MySQL
- cache > Ehcache
- Hibernate 2nd Lvl cache > Y
- lib mgmt > Gradle
- JHipster registry > No
- Websocket using spring websocket
- frontend framework > vue
- admin UI > Y
- theme > default
- int. support > Y
- Junit & Jest > cypress, gatling, cucumber

1. what is wrong with the setup or do I need to configure something more?
2. Can I replace the frontend vue theme with vuetify?

[Edit]

So far;
I don't have problems logging in (authenticating) with Jhipster build with angular as the front end.
NPM version 7+
JHipster version 7.1.0

After setting up with the standard blueprint, I run the server with

> gradlew -x webapp

and another open terminal to run the vue front end

> npm start

The frontend page open at localhost:9000 and backend at 8080. Whenever I try to logged in, the log at server look like this.

[image: Screenshot]

and the log for the server terminal:

> 2021-07-14 12:29:37.488 DEBUG 20748 --- [  XNIO-1 task-5] m.c.app.web.rest.AccountResource         : Enter: getAccount() with argument[s] = []
> 2021-07-14 12:29:37.489 DEBUG 20748 --- [  XNIO-1 task-5] my.cermatapp.app.service.UserService     : Enter: getUserWithAuthorities() with argument[s] = []
> 2021-07-14 12:29:37.489 DEBUG 20748 --- [  XNIO-1 task-5] my.cermatapp.app.service.UserService     : Exit: getUserWithAuthorities() with result = Optional[User{login='admin', firstName='Administrator', lastName='Administrator', email='admin@localhost', imageUrl='', activated='true', langKey='en', activationKey='null'}]
> 2021-07-14 12:29:37.489 DEBUG 20748 --- [  XNIO-1 task-5] m.c.app.web.rest.AccountResource         : Exit: getAccount() with result = AdminUserDTO{login='admin', firstName='Administrator', lastName='Administrator', email='admin@localhost', imageUrl='', activated=true, langKey='en', createdBy=system, createdDate=null, lastModifiedBy='system', lastModifiedDate=null, authorities=[ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]}
> 2021-07-14 12:29:37.575  WARN 20748 --- [  XNIO-1 task-3] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Forbidden: Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.
> 2021-07-14 12:29:37.576  WARN 20748 --- [  XNIO-1 task-3] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.InvalidCsrfTokenException: Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.]

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details: do you see any error in browser's console? How did you start backend and front servers?Which version of JHipster? And for vuetify the answer is yes if you modify manually generated code or if you write a JHipster blueprint.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question with a screenshot for reference.

Comment: Can you try to use JWT instead of session with vue?

Comment: I have reproduced the issue with Vue, however it does work with Angular (same options, only different frontend) so it's clearly a bug in Vue implementation.

Comment: @atomfrede I will try a bit later. today The idea is I want a vue + spring build that can run session and oauth2. Thanks for the suggestion.